# PowerShell ParamArray

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to create a function that supports a param array, similar to the ParamArray in VB.Net:

```
function foo{ 

   param(
     $a,
     $b, 
     [Array]$arr
   )

   write-host "a: $a"
   write-host "b: $b"   
   write-host "arr: $arr"

   Foreach($s in $arr) {
     write-host $s
   }

} 

PS> foo -a "abc" -b "123" -c 456 -d 789
```

Unfortunately, parameters 'c' and 'd' are not found.  Is there a way to structure the `Param()`definition to do support my needs?

Comment: If your script only needs the input as an array, why not use `foo -a "abc" -b "123" -arr 456, 789`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell has the `$args` automatic variable that contains any extra parameters.

Try running:

```
function foo {
    param(
        $a,
        $b
    )

    "a: $a"
    "b: $b"
    foreach($arg in $args) { 
        "Arg: $arg"
    }
}

foo -a 1 -b 2 3 4 5
```

Output:

```
a: 1
b: 2
Arg: 3
Arg: 4
Arg: 5
```